# Platform independent Qt5 way to get open TCP port

Tags: qt, tcp, cross-platform, port, qt5

Is there a platform independent way in Qt to get an unused TCP port? I have a need to launch an existing application which must be given an open TCP port in order for it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use QTcpServer is easier way.

`bool QTcpServer::listen(const QHostAddress & address = QHostAddress::Any, quint16 port = 0)`

If `port` is 0, a `port` is chosen automatically, then you use `quint16 QTcpServer::serverPort() const` to get the "idle" port

then close your Tcp Server

OR

generate a ramdom port, use `QTcpSocket` to connect it(local connection)

1. if connected, your port is `QTcpSocket::localPort()` and close this tcp socket
2. if not connected, your port is random port;

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean some kind of tcp server? Then there is [QTcpServer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html)  class.

If you want to start an existiong server, then you need QProcess class. Example:

```
QString program = "path/to/server";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-p" << "1234"; //or what ever you want

QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use a QTcpServer. The existing application that I need to launch is essentially it's own TCP server. But to start it, I need to pass a command line option with the TCP port on which that application should bind.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then you need `QProcess` class.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I know how to kick off a process in Qt. My question is how do I find the "1234" part? This has to be a platform independent way to get an unused TCP port.